# How to optimize the tangent equation of a curve at a certain point?

Tags: plotting

How to optimize the tangent equation of a curve at a certain point as follows：

**How to draw the images of the original function, derivative function and tangent equation into the same coordinate system?**

```
ClearAll["`*"]
f[x_] := Log[1 + x] + x E^-x
g[x_] := D[f[x], x] // FullSimplify
point = {0, f[0]}
point[[1]]
k = D[f[x], x] /. x -> point[[1]]
y - point[[2]] == k (x - point[[1]])
Plot[{f[x], g[x],%}, {x, -1, 2}]
```

Update 1:

```
f[x_] = Log[1 + x] + x E^-x;
point = {0, f[0]}
k = D[f[x], x] /. x -> point[[1]]
y - point[[2]] == k (x - point[[1]])
Plot[{f[x], f'[x]}, {x, -1, 4}, 
 Epilog -> {Red, 
   InfiniteLine[{x, f[x]}, D[{x, f[x]}, x]] /. x -> point[[1]]}, 
 PlotLabels -> "Expressions", AspectRatio -> 1]
```

Update 2:

```
Clear[f, expr];
f[x_] = Log[1 + x] + x E^-x;
point = {2, f[2]}
k = D[f[x], x] /. x -> point[[1]]
y - point[[2]] == k (x - point[[1]])
expr = {f[x], f'[x], f[x0] + f'[x0] (x - x0) /. x0 -> point[[1]]} // 
   Evaluate;
Plot[expr, {x, -1, 7}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
 PlotLabels -> Thread[{"f(x)", "f'(x)", "y"} == expr], 
 ImageSize -> Full]
```

Update 3

```
Clear[f, expr];
f[x_] = Log[1 + x] + x E^-x; point = {0, f[0]} 
k = D[f[x], x] /. x -> point[[1]]
 y - point[[2]] == k (x - point[[1]]) 
expr = {f[x], f'[x], f[x0] + f'[x0] (x - x0) /. x0 -> point[[1]]} // 
  Evaluate; 
Plot[expr, {x, -1, 7}, 
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[point], 
   Text[point, point, {-2, 1}]}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
 PlotLabels -> Thread[{"f(x)", "f'(x)", "y"} == expr], 
 ImageSize -> 500]
```

Update 4:

```
Clear[f, expr];
f[x_] = Log[x] + E^(x - 1);
point = {1, f[1]} 
k = D[f[x], x] /. x -> point[[1]]
 y - point[[2]] == k (x - point[[1]]) 
expr = {f[x], f'[x], 
   f[x0] + f'[x0] (x - x0) /. x0 -> point[[1]] // FullSimplify} // 
  Evaluate; Plot[expr, {x, -1, 7}, 
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[point], 
   Text[point, point, {-2, 1}]}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
 PlotLabels -> Thread[{"f(x)", "f'(x)", "y"} == expr], 
 ImageSize -> 500]
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by optimizing? Also, your choice of tags is befuddling

Comment: What about `Normal[Series[f[x], {x, x0, 1}]] `?

Comment: How to draw the images of the original function, derivative function and tangent equation into the same coordinate system?

Comment: `f[x],f'[x]`need one argument `x` but tangent equation needs two arguments `x,x0`! That's why it's necessary to choose `x0` before plotting

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit**

```
Clear[f,expr];
f[x_] = Log[1 + x] + x E^-x;
expr = {f[x], f'[x], f[x0] + f'[x0] (x - x0) /. x0 -> 0} // Evaluate;
Plot[expr, {x, -1, 4}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
 PlotLabels -> Thread[{"f(x)", "f'(x)", "y"} == expr]]
```

[image]

**Original**

```
Clear[f];
f[x_] = Log[1 + x] + x E^-x;
Plot[{f[x], D[f[x], x]} // Evaluate, {x, -1, 4}, 
 Epilog -> {Red, InfiniteLine[{x, f[x]}, D[{x, f[x]}, x]] /. x -> 0}, 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
 PlotLabels -> {Style["f(x)", 14, Blue], Style["f'(x)", 14, Blue]}]
```

[image]

Comment: (+1) but it should be `f[x_] = Log[1 + x] + x E^-x;
Plot[Evaluate[{f[x], D[f[x], x]}], {x, -1, 4}, 
 Epilog -> {Red, InfiniteLine[{x, f[x]}, D[{x, f[x]}, x]] /. x -> 0}]` In the OP it is stated the function, its derivative and the tangent line :-)

Comment: ```PlotLabels -> "Expressions"```Plus, why can't the complete function analytic expression be displayed next to each curve in the image? How to display tangent equations next to tangents

Comment: Can I display the complete analytical formula of the function next to the curve? And f (x)=......,

Comment: The tangent equation should be y==2x

Comment: Also mark the location and tangent point in the figure

Comment: ```Clear[f, expr];
f[x_] = Log[1 + x] + x E^-x;
point = {2, f[2]}
k = D[f[x], x] /. x -> point[[1]]
y - point[[2]] == k (x - point[[1]])
expr = {f[x], f'[x], f[x0] + f'[x0] (x - x0) /. x0 -> point[[1]]} // 
   Evaluate;
Plot[expr, {x, -1, 7}, 
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[point], Text[point]}, 
 AspectRatio -> 1, 
 PlotLabels -> Thread[{"f(x)", "f'(x)", "y"} == expr], 
 ImageSize -> Full]```How can I put the coordinate value next to the tangent point?

Comment: ```Clear[f, expr];
f[x_] = Log[1 + x] + x E^-x;
point = {0, f[0]}
k = D[f[x], x] /. x -> point[[1]]
y - point[[2]] == k (x - point[[1]])
expr = {f[x], f'[x], f[x0] + f'[x0] (x - x0) /. x0 -> point[[1]]} // 
   Evaluate;
Plot[expr, {x, -1, 7}, 
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[point], 
   Text[point, point + {1, 1}]}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
 PlotLabels -> Thread[{"f(x)", "f'(x)", "y"} == expr], 
 ImageSize -> Full]```Excessive offset

Comment: @csn899  `Clear[f, expr]; 
f[x_] = Log[1 + x] + x E^-x; point = {0, f[0]}; k = 
 D[f[x], x] /. 
  x -> point[[1]] y - point[[2]] == k (x - point[[1]]); expr = {f[x], 
   f'[x], f[x0] + f'[x0] (x - x0) /. x0 -> point[[1]]} // 
  Evaluate; Plot[expr, {x, -1, 7}, 
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[point], 
   Text[point, point, {-1, 1}]}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
 PlotLabels -> Thread[{"f(x)", "f'(x)", "y"} == expr], 
 ImageSize -> 400]`

Answer (score 4):

Maybe I am missing something, but I don't see what.

Anyway, with a minimal amendment of the code in the OP we have:

```
f[x_] := Log[1 + x] + x E^-x
g[x_] := D[f[x], x] // FullSimplify
point = {0, f[0]}
point[[1]]
k = D[f[x], x] /. x -> point[[1]]
p0 = ContourPlot[
   y - point[[2]] == k (x - point[[1]]), {x, 0, 4}, {y, 0, 2}];
p1 = Plot[Evaluate[{f[x], g[x]}], {x, 0, 4}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Red, Green}];
Show[p0, p1]
Show[p1, p0]
```

> [image: plot]

> [image: p2]